# Architecture of Online Chess (2-player web-based board game)?

Tags: architecture, web-applications, game-development

I'd like to try to create an application where 2 players can play chess online. The (possibly) novel feature would be that the process for joining a game would be similar to how Typeracer works. The first player creates a lobby then shares a link. The friend can then click the link to join the session immediately.

However, I'm a beginner when it comes to how information is shared over the internet. I've only created a few REST APIs and games in Java/Python so a lot of this would be new to me.

The first question I have is how/where would I actually implement the logic for this game? Would everything be done client-side (I'd probably use React so I'd then have a js library to hold all game rules) Or is everything done on the server?

Also, how would I keep the player's game clients in sync? I've heard about websockets but any elaboration would be helpful.

Lastly, how could I go about implementing the feature where users can share their game link to get the other player to join?

For context, I have quite a bit of experience with React for UI, I've used NodeJS on the server, and I'm currently learning about how to create web APIs with ASP.NET web API (C#). I figure that I'll be able to create the board UI in React and handle any animations with CSS. If that's not a good idea let me know!

Overall I'm not really sure how I'll tie this all together so a big picture view might help; and I've love to hear about any frameworks or tools that might make this job easier; thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: So what exactly is the question? As it stands all I can really say is: Yes, you've got as high level description of your problem. Keep on working on it.

Comment: @Kain0_0 Looking for advice on how people have dealt with the 3 problems stated, and any other help I could get so I don't go down the wrong path. But yes, I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first question I have is how/where would I actually implement the logic for this game? Would everything be done client-side (I'd probably use React so I'd then have a js library to hold all game rules) Or is everything done on the server?

That's completely up to you. I've done exactly this with a project that used no fixed server. It was fully peer to peer. But someone has to be able to publicly open ports.

> Also, how would I keep the player's game clients in sync? I've heard about websockets but any elaboration would be helpful.

We did it with a timestamped md5 digest of the game state. So long as that matched we knew things were good. If it failed we resynced state. A digest might be a bit much for chess since its state is small. We were letting you play any board game in existance.

> Lastly, how could I go about implementing the feature where users can share their game link to get the other player to join?

A connection string needs a ip and a port. Just let your player copy that into an email/chat/post it with their friend and they're good to go.

If you have a fixed server this can become a URL with a site and a protocol.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! I'Il look into these things.